# Why Do Two Object.create() Calls Result in a Merge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I don't understand how to work with Object.create() in JavaScript.  Why, in this code, do two objects a and b merge whereas they were declared in two different contexts?

```
var l = {
   a: null,
   b: null
}

function a() {
    var a = Object.create(l);
    a.a = "a";
    console.log('a : ', a.a, a.b);
}

function b() {
    var b = Object.create(l);
    b.b = "b";
    console.log('b : ' + b.a, b.b);
}

function main() {
   a();
   b();
}

main();
```

And this is the output :

```
a :  a null
b :  a b
```

How I can isolate them ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @E43B5B I ran the code example you provide and get a different result where no merge occurs; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistook `Object.create` with something like `Object.assign`:

```
// This is not what you want
var a = Object.create(l);

// Do this instead
var a = Object.assign({}, l);
```

If you want the objects of the functions to be "isolated" (I guess you are talking about not having side-effects) you want to create new objects, by using for instance `Object.assign` (and not `Object.create`).

Comment: May you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of **Object.create** is to create a new object based on the prototype of its parameter; see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more info. In running the OP's source code, I found the result surprising; see for yourself:

```js
var l = {
   a: null,
   b: null
}

function a() {
    var a = Object.create(l);
    a.a = "a";
    console.log('a : ', a.a, a.b);
}

function b() {
    var b = Object.create(l);
    b.b = "b";
    console.log('b : ' + b.a, b.b);
}

function main() {
   a();
   b();
}

main();
```

Two objects get created based on a prototype `object l` and the properties of the two new objects remain independent from one another. Function a() alters `obj a` by setting its `property a` with a value of "a" and  its `property b` remains null -- the result is logged by the console. Function b() behaves in a similar fashion with respect to `obj b`, setting its `property b` to "b" while its `property a` remains null.

A merge results if you use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) without specifying an object target, such as `{}`. Additionally, a merge can occur if you force Object.create to be an alias for Object.assign, as follows:

```js
// Very bad idea but feasible:
Object.create = Object.assign;

var l = {
   a: null,
   b: null
}

function a() {
    var a = Object.create(l);
    a.a = "a";
    console.log('a : ', a.a, a.b);
}

function b() {
    var b = Object.create(l);
    b.b = "b";
    console.log('b : ' + b.a, b.b);
}

function main() {
   a();
   b();
}

main();
```

This code illustrates the consequences of making `object l` due double-duty as both the object to assign and the target object. Also, note the ease JavaScript affords one to create a misleading alias.